# Use where in row collection in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I have below classes :

1. News
2. PostPermission
3. Role

each News Have ListOfPostPermissions(1-many) and each PostPermission have one Role (1-1).

I have  List of `RoleId` and I want to get all `News` where `PostPermission`'s `RoleId` is in the List of `RoleId`.

I use below code but It throws error :

```
var roles = _currentUserService.GetCurrentUserRoles(); // List<Guid>
return NewsList.Where(row => row.Permissions.Where(role=>roles.Contains( role.RoleId)).ToList()).ToList();
```

I getting these errors:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to
> 'bool'
>
> Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func'
> because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly
> convertible to the delegate return type

how can I do it ?

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Any` inside, instead of `Where` like this

```
return NewsList
    .Where(row => row.Permissions.Any(role=>roles.Contains(role.RoleId)))
    .ToList();
```

This is because the outer `Where` expects a predicate, i.e. expression that returns a `bool`. This is clearly indicated by the first exception message.

Comment: your code return this error :`'bool' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'bool' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: I deleted First `ToList` like this `return NewsList.Where(row =>row.Permissions.Any(role=>roles.Contains(role.RoleId))).ToList();` and it does not have Error now , It's right ?

Comment: @PsarTak Sorry, I didn't look carefully at the whole query, since the replacement of  the `Where` with `Any` was the essential part. Corrected the answer.